# Selenium - How to send file path to dynamically generated input element (not present in dom)

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, selenium

here is an example

html

```
<button id="visible-btn">visible button</button>
<p>selected file is: <span id="selected-file"></span></p>
```

javascript (usually hidden deep inside)

```
document.getElementById('visible-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e){

    const ele = document.createElement('input');
    ele.type = 'file';
    ele.accept = '*';

    ele.onchange = function (e){
        document.getElementById('selected-file').innerText = e.path[0].files[0].name;
    }

    ele.click();
})
```

since the input element is not present in the dom, i cannot use below python code to send the file path

```
file_path = '/path/to/file'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input').send_keys(file_path)
```

any idea how to solve this?
much appreciated

---

**edit 1**

issue is from facebook creator studio [https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/published?content_table=POSTED_POSTS&post_type=FB_SHORTS]

"Create new" button opens the file select dialog

[image]

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand how DOMs work; doesn't the javascript `document.createElement('input')` mean at that point in time, there would be an input element on the DOM? Even if only for an instant?

Comment: as per my understanding, document.createElement('input') creates an element but thats it.  element will not be injected into the dom unless we use a method like appendChild

Comment: "Even if only for an instant?" did not think about that. will check. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to send uploaded file to a wrong element.
The uploaded file should be sent to element element located by this XPath: `//input[@type='file']`. This element is not visible and it should not be dynamic.
So your code should be:

```py
file_path = '/path/to/file'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys(file_path)
```

Comment: No this wont work. input element is not present in the dom. it is created using javascript and never injected into the dom. will get NoSuchElementException

Comment: Have to tried to wait for that element presence? Not to be clickable or visible, just presence.

Comment: there is no input element in html. never.

Comment: I see. That sound strange, but I indeed saw such pages.

Comment: what was your solution ?

Comment: I saw such page in some question here and I could not resolve it. I don't know. Maybe this can not be automated with Selenium.

Comment: @GayanJeewantha do you have a page sample we can see?  I'm having a hard time comprehending a page that has an field the user can interact with but that does not actually exist in the DOM.

Comment: @MarcelWilson edit 1

Comment: Oh wow. I see what you mean. Where did you find the javascript being used by the "Create New" button?  I'd like to see it.

Comment: i have seen similar functionality with other websites. the above javascript example is my guess on how this could be achieved. facebook uses react.